# Stop postgreSQL service on Mac via terminal

Tags: macos, postgresql, pg, launchctl

Running postgreSQL 9.4.5_2 currently

I have tried

```
pg_ctl stop -W -t 1 -s -D /usr/local/var/postgres -m f
```

Normally no news is good news but after I will run

```
pg_ctl status -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

and get `pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 536)`

I have also tried

```
pg_ctl restart -w -D /usr/local/var/postgres -c -m i
```

Response message is:

```
waiting for server to shut down.......................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

I've also checked my /Library/LaunchDaemons/ to see why the service is starting at login but no luck so far. Anyone have any ideas on where I should check next? Force quit in the activity monitor also isn't helping me any.

Answer (score 54):

Sadly none of the previous answers help me, it worked for me with:

```
brew services stop postgresql
```

Cheers

Comment: may need to specify version: `brew services stop postgresql@15`

Answer (score 25):

Restart it with

```
sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data stop
```

Comment: This is great, but one note - your command assumes you are in the same directory as the `pg_ctl` binary. Usually whatever install process you went through to get Postgres onto your machine puts that binary on a directory in your path. So what probably works more universally is `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/11/data stop`

Comment: Good solution. But not `./pg_ctl`. Please use `pg_ctl`.

Comment: It doesn't work if your path is on a user directory (e.g. in `~/` because of permission issues. Run `cd /` to avoid file permissions issues when you switch the postgres user, which doesn't have access to your user home directory.

Answer (score 20):

Tried sudo and su but no such luck. 
Just found this gui

https://github.com/MaccaTech/postgresql-mac-preferences

If anyone can help with the terminal commands that would be very much appreciated, but till then the gui will get the job done.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue, I had installed postgres locally and wanted to wrap in a docker container instead.

I solved it pretty radically by 1) uninstalling postgres 2) kill the leftover process on postgres port. If you don't un-install the process restarts and grabs the port again - look at your Brewfile form `brew bundle dump` to check for a `restart_service: true` flag.

I reasoned that, as I am using containers, I should not need the local one anyway, but **!! attention this will remove postgres from your system**.

```
brew uninstall postgres
...
lsof -i :5432 # this to find the PID for the process
kill - 9 <the PID you found at previous command>
```

Note: if you still want to used `psql` you can `brew install libpq`, and add psql to your PATH (the command output shows you what to add to your `.zshrc`, or similar)

Answer (score 8):

you can stop the server using this command

```
{pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast}
```

Comment: pg_ctl is not on my path.  Where is it normally installed?

Answer (score 4):

I just installed Postgres 15 on OS X Ventura and also could not figure out how to stop it. The following worked:

```
sudo -u postgres /Library/PostgreSQL/15/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/15/data stop
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto the solutions already stated :

if you decide to use the `pg_ctl` command,  ensure that you are executing the command as a user with the permissions to access the databases/database server.

this means :

- the current logged in user on your terminal should have those permissions

or

- first run :

```
$ sudo su <name_of_database_user>

pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/<version_here>/data/ stop
```

the same goes for the start command.

credit : https://gist.github.com/kingbin/9435292
(essentially hosted a file with the commands on github, saved me some time :^) )

Answer (score 2):

I had a stray docker container running Postgres that I had forgotten about.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible scenario is when you installed PostgreSQL via UI, the command to find the process is:

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 5432
```

Then you kill the PID

```
kill -9 PID_FROM_netstat
```

Comment: Almost any managed process is going to auto respawn if you just manually kill the process